# replace negative values with na using na_if{dplyr}

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~V1, ~V2, 
  2, -3,
  3, 2, 
  1, 3, 
  3, -4,
  5, 1, 
  3, 2, 
  1, -4,
  3, 4, 
  4, 1, 
  3, -5,
  4, 2, 
  3, 4 
)
```

How can I replace negative values with NA using `na_if()`? I know how to do this using `ifelse`, but don't manage to come up with a correct condition for `na_if()`:

```
> dat %>%
+   mutate(V2 = ifelse(V2 < 0, NA, V2))

# A tibble: 12 x 2
      V1    V2
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2    NA
 2     3     2
 3     1     3
 4     3    NA
 5     5     1
 6     3     2
 7     1    NA
 8     3     4
 9     4     1
10     3    NA
11     4     2
12     3     4
```

Comment: You can't.  `na_if()` is for replacing specific values and doesn't work with logical conditions.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Do you want to put this in an answer? Then I could accept the answer.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento as far as i can see, that is not strictly true. you can replace numbers >0  (to a degree). for some reason it doesn't work for negative numbers

Comment: @D.J - that's not correct.  It might have worked for you accidentally but it does not work in general.  Please post a working example.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento
i am not saying you are wrong! just technically na_if() allows for the use of >. check `na_if(dat$V2, dat$V2 > 0)` the result sets all values == 1 to NA. so you are right of course - just *strictly* speaking `>` and `<` are possible. the point being, that it can be confusing when using `na_if()`

Comment: The `y` argument is vectorized so it accepts input the same length as `x` - see the example in the docs `na_if(1:5, 5:1)`.  But It is not replacing using the condition given.  The only values that will ever get replaced using a logical condition are `0` and `1`. Totally agree that the behavior can be confusing.